# Location for XSD file used for validation during RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, rspec, xsd

I am building XML files inside my application and I would like to validate the generated XML's format against an XSD file. I am not sure where shall I put this `schema.xsd` file so that it can be easily retrieved inside an RSpec example.

I was thinking about putting it inside `spec/support`, but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest spec/fixtures, since it is part of your test suite, it's somewhat static data and it can be accessed easily via fixture_path (you can set any other *_path helper in your spec_helper file if you wish to).

Comment: But it's not quite a fixture, not even close to it. I would rather put it somewhere else, since `spec/fixtures` expects _true_ fixtures inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up putting my `.xsd` file in `spec/support/schemas/`; it felt more natural for me, since it is a *support* file.